# jQuery - Dynamically slide up Div over an image when mouse over it

Tags: jquery, image

I need to dynamically show a div over an image when mouse over. I need to do this for a lot of images so it needs to be dynamic. I looked at the code from [www.foliostars.net](http://www.foliostars.net/) :

```
jQuery.fn.masque = function(classe) {

$(this).hover(function(){
$(this).find(classe).stop().animate({height:'40px',opacity: '0.9'},400);
},function () { 
$(this).find(classe).stop().animate({height:'0',opacity: '0'}, 400);
});
}   
$(document).ready(function(){$('.thumb h2').masque('.masque');});
```

There is a way to modify this for using a div instead of a header??
There is maybe a better way to do it??

Thanks!

Comment: There is a problem with this code in IE7. And probably also in IE6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Give your divs a class `"slider"`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('div.slider').masque('.masque');});
```